# Trigger no sql server management studio

Tags: sql-server, trigger

Eu gostaria de criar um Trigger no MSSMS (Sql Server) que, se eu fizesse um INSERT em uma tabela A, com o último registro da tabela B, ele inserisse mais 10 registros na tabela B, e assim sucessivamente sempre que usasse o último criasse mais 10. Mas não sei como fazer a verificação de 'último registro', ou último objeto naquela tabela. Alguém saberia como fazer isso?

Comment: Você está utlizando alguma aplicação ? ou  está apenas criando  a query  para rodar no  sql manager ?
Deixe o  maxímo de informação possivel para que possamos ajudar, há N jeitos de obter o ultimo registro em um banco de dados, dependendo  mais do que você está utilizando

Comment: Estou criando a query pra rodar no sql manager, mas tenho uma aplicação. Não sei quais informações seriam interessantes.. No meu banco a tabela A tem uma ForeignKey da tabela B como um dos campos.

Comment: @RayaneNascimento (1) Há algum motivo para utilizar procedimento de gatilho para resolver isto? Não poderia ser feito na própria aplicação? (2) Poderia acrescentar no texto da pergunta detalhes das tabelas envolvidas? Basta clicar no link `editar`, ok? (3) Nesse processo de acrescentar 10 linhas na tabela B é necessário cuidado com a concorrência de processos para evitar duplicidades...